# Cual es el problema con Command line Arguments

Tags: go

Hola hace poco empeze con Go, estoy intentando obtener input pero cuando hago `go run Main.go` me devuelve `package command-line-arguments is not a main package` cuando hago `go build Main.go` no devuelve ni error ni ejecutable cual puede ser el error?

Main.go:

```
package Main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var Input string

func Main() {
    //Start a bufio reader
    Reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Input: ")
    Input, _ := Reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Println("Command: ", Input)
}
```

go.mod:

```
module Main

go 1.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go es sensible a Mayuscula y minusculas dentro del codigo y esto puede significar cosas diferentes para el compilador, coloca main con Minuscula. Ejemplo: para una funcion comenzar con minuscula convierte esa funcion en privada y si es Mayuscula es publica.

```
    package main

    func main() {
        //Start a bufio reader
        Reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("Input: ")
        Input, _ := Reader.ReadString('\n')
    
        fmt.Println("Command: ", Input)
    }
```

```
    module main
    
    go 1.17
```

Comment: Muchas gracias algo nuevo aprendido aceptare la pregunta cuando Stack me deje :)